# Rails: Keep JSON form fields populated if the form returns a validation error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

I have a rails simple form that creates a product and I have the following three fields inside the form in order to associate the product with the appropriate categories:

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <%= f.input :child_category_id, :collection => @categories.order(:name), :label_method => :name, :value_method => :id, label: "Category", :include_blank => "--Select Category--", input_html: { id: "first_dropdown" } %>
 </div>

 <div class="show_hide">
   <%= f.input :subcategory_id, :collection => [] || @subcategory.order(:name), :label_method => :name, :value_method => :id, label: false, :include_blank => "--Select Category--", input_html: { id: "second_dropdown" } %>
 </div>

 <div class="show_hide_third">
   <%= f.input :child_subcategory_id, :collection => [] || @child_subcategory.order(:name), :label_method => :name, :value_method => :id, label: false, input_html: { id: "third_dropdown" } %>
 </div>
```

This is the route:

```
resources :products, :path => "products/select_item", only: [:select_item] do
  get :select_item, on: :collection
end
```

This is the method inside the controller I have:

```
def select_item
  if params[:child_category_id].present?
    @subcategory = Subcategory.where(child_category_id: params[:child_category_id])
    render :json => @subcategory.order(:name)
  end
  if params[:subcategory_id].present?
    @child_subcategory = ChildSubcategory.where(subcategory_id: params[:subcategory_id])
    render :json => @child_subcategory.order(:name)
    end
end
```

This is the new product and create product methods I have inside the controller:

```
def new; end

def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
        format.json { render :new, status: :created, location: @product }
        flash[:success] = "Product was successfully added."
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

This is the Javascript I'm using in order to populate the second and third field, according to the selected value:

```
    $('#first_dropdown').on('change', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/products/select_item/select_item?child_category_id=' + $(this).val(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                let childElement = $('#second_dropdown');
                if( data.length === 0 ) {
                    $('.show_hide').hide();
                    $('.show_hide_third').hide();
                } else {
                    $('.show_hide').show();
                }
                childElement.html('');
                data.forEach(function(v) {
                    let id = v.id;
                    let name = v.name;
                    childElement.append('<option value="' + id + '">' + name + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    });

    $('#second_dropdown').on('change', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/products/select_item/select_item?subcategory_id=' + $(this).val(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                let childElement = $('#third_dropdown');
                if( data.length === 0 ) {
                    $('.show_hide').hide();
                    $('.show_hide_third').hide();
                } else {
                    $('.show_hide').show();
                    $('.show_hide_third').show();
                }
                childElement.html('');
                data.forEach(function(v) {
                    let id = v.id;
                    let name = v.name;
                    childElement.append('<option value="' + id + '">' + name + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Everything works just fine and all the fields get populated correctly. The only issue I'm having is that when the form renders again, due to a validation error, the JSON fields show up empty, even though they were correctly populated. How can I keep the JSON form fields populated even if the form returns a validation error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that at the point the page loads there are no options in your dropdown to select from; therefore the form cannot select the correct value. You need to update your controller like this:

```rb
def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
        format.json { render :new, status: :created, location: @product }
        flash[:success] = "Product was successfully added."
      else
        @categories = Category.all.order(:name)
        @subcategory = Subcategory.where(child_category_id: @product.child_category_id).order(:name)
        @child_subcategory = ChildSubcategory.where(subcategory_id: @product.subcategory_id).order(:name)
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @TomDunning... it works just fine! :))))

Comment: No problem, glad I could help @Dev :)

Comment: @Dev you may want the same thing on edit and update, if editing is an option.

Comment: I just made the changes on edit and update.... thanks again!!